# Phonegap для сайта

Tags: phonegap, javascript

Объясните phonegap будет работать для сайта без компиляции в приложения?

Мне например, хочется сделать на сайте возможность делать снимок с камеры и сразу прикреплять его к форме. В phonegap есть такая библиотека.

Comment: Мсье знает толк в извращениях. Вот вам [статья][1], почитайте её и не пытайтесь больше почесать правое ухо левой тройкой векторов.

  [1]: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Только если в браузер встроят phonegap :)*

По делу: используйте чистый [html5](https://www.google.ru/search?ie=UTF-8&hl=ru&q=html5%20audio%20api)

Answer (score 0):

Нет, не будет работать.

Есть разные решения такого рода задач, например [это](http://html5.by/blog/html5-image-capture-getusermedia-stream-api-mirror/), но кроссбраузерность не гарантируется.